# How to run JFrame maximized in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to JAVA.

I need to run a JFrame named `MainFrame` in maximized mode.

How can I do it?

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MainFrame
 */
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use [`JFrame.setExtendedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29):

```java
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Comment: The last time I used Red Hat Enterprise Linux, the frame must be visible in order to set the extended state. It worked fine on windows despite the order. I'm not sure if this is still an issue.

Comment: Just tested this on Windows 8.1: The frame had to be visible in order for it to work.